# PHP cURL provides SSL-Error AFTER sending the data?

Tags: php, post, curl, ssl, ssl-certificate

This is my Code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $apiUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postValues);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Now the $result is "false" and the curl_error() shows me the SSL-Error "Peer's Certificate issuer is not recognized.".
But although there is this error, the post data has been sent to the $apiUrl.

Is this correct? Bug or feature? ;)

How can I improve this to prevent sending data to an insecure service?

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the reason why the data has been transfered although there has been a curl error!
There was a redirect to another location and with "followlocation" active, the error happened on the redirected site!
So the data has been sent to the $apiUrl and has been processed. After this the curl call has been redirected and the error appeared.

My trust in logic has been restored :D

Answer (score 4):

There is two solution for this...

### Solution - 1

If you want to skip check SSL certificate use....

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
```

### Solution - 2

If you have certificate with you use....

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "PATH_TO/cacert.pem");
```

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but disabling completely the validation is the worst "solution" and updating the cacert.pem is also not a solution, because my question is how to prevent sending the data BEFORE this error happens. I know how to fix the error, but I wonder why the data has been sent.

Comment: From php 5.5, new option is available in curl_setopt and that is CURLOPT_CONNECT_ONLY which tells the library to perform all the required proxy authentication and connection setup, but no data transfer. [CURLOPT_CONNECT_ONLY](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)

Answer (score 0):

This is incorrect; cURL does not send any data when there is a problem with the SSL certificate.

(I just tested with a connection to a local script - the second script did not run when the first script encountered an SSL error while connecting to it.)

Comment: This is definitly one of the weirdest things it ever happend... meanwhile I cannot reproduce this error and now there is no data sent if there is a problem with the SSL certificate... but it happend, trust me, this freaks me out >.< :(